# AJAX ReferenceError: value is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax

есть код с формой

```
<form action="action.php">
    <div>
        <div>Пол</div>
            <div>
                <input id="sex" name="sex" value="1" type="radio"> М
                <input id="sex" name="sex" value="2" type="radio"> Ж
            </div>
    </div>
    <input type='button' value='Редактировать' onclick='
        ajax({
            url:"action.php",
            statbox:"status",
            method:"POST",
            data:
                {
                    sex:value,
                },
            success:function(data) document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=data;}
        })\'
    >
</form>
```

и после формы ниже такой скрипт

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[name=sex]").change(function() {
        var value = $("input[name=sex]:checked").val();
    });
</script>
```

После нажатия на кнопку выскакивает ошибка из заголовка вопроса.
Отдельно ajax, если переменной sex явно указать значение, нормально срабатывает. И скрипт, если  alert(value); поставить срабатывает правильно. А вместе не хотят.

Еще одно примечание. Если использовать не type="radio", а checkbox, то все работает как по часам.

Подскажите, что не так я сделал с type="radio" ?

Comment: Удалите `var`. P.S. Хотя, код надо переписывать.

Comment: Помогло с var!  Спасибо) А напишите в ответах это. Я вам галочку поставлю, так тут вроде принято.

Comment: А не лучше ли `var value = $("input[name=sex]:checked").val();` написать непосредственно перед запросом ajax? ajax вынести в функцию, которая будет срабатывать при клике. И там же будет браться значение `sex`. И даже не придется постоянно теребить `onchange`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы вам предложил сделать так:

Ajax запрос вынести в функцию. И при клике на кнопку редактировать брать значение `sex` и передавать, не мучая событие `onchange`, т.е. `onchange` вообще выкинуть. Оно тут не особо нужно.

будет как-то так:

```
function editVal() {
    var sex = $("input[name=sex]:checked").val();

    ajax({
        url:"action.php",
        statbox:"status",
        method:"POST",
        data: {sex: sex},
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = data;
        }
    })

    return false;
}
```

html

`<input type='button' value='Редактировать' onclick='editVal();' />`